# Graph doesn't looking correct after running rpart

Tags: r, plot, rpart

The goal of this code to run rpart to create a model to predict quality/wine quality. I then tried to graph the in-sample and out of sample from validating the model. The plot outputted has number of leaves as the x and loss on the y.

Here is my code:

```
# rm(list=ls())

### read the dataset and make sure to change the diresctory
wine_quality <- read.csv("C:/Users/machu/Documents/data_analytics_program/wine_quality.csv")

### there are some data missing, I have come up several ways to deal with that: 
  # there are pros and cons for both. I will leave this to you guys which way to choose

## 1. drop rows that include na
wine_quality = na.omit(wine_quality)

## 2. replace the na with the mean of the columns
# for(i in 1:ncol(wine_quality)){
#     wine_quality[is.na(wine_quality[,i]), i] <- mean(wine_quality[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
# }


### changing quality to factor type
wine_quality$quality <- factor(wine_quality$quality)
wine_quality$type <- factor(wine_quality$type )

### rpart
library(rpart)
library(tree)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rattle)

#train, val, test
set.seed(99)
n=nrow(wine_quality)
n1=floor(n/2)
n2=floor(n/4)
n3=n-n1-n2
ii = sample(1:n,n)
train = wine_quality[ii[1:n1],]
train = subset(train, select = -1)
val = wine_quality[ii[n1+1:n2],]
val = subset(val, select = -1)

test = wine_quality[ii[n1+n2+1:n3],]
test = subset(test, select = -1)

### get big tree at first
big.tree = rpart(quality~.,
                 method="class", 
                 data=train, 
                 control=rpart.control(minsplit=5, 
                                       cp=.0001))
nbig = length(unique(big.tree$where))
cat('Number of leaf nodes: ',nbig,'\n')

cpvec = big.tree$cptable[,"CP"] #cp values to try
ntree = length(cpvec) #number of cv values = number of trees fit.
iltree = rep(0,ntree) #in-sample loss
oltree = rep(0,ntree) #out-of-sample loss
sztree = rep(0,ntree) #size of each tree
for(i in 1:ntree) {
  if((i %% 5)==0) cat('tree i: ',i, "out of", ntree, '\n')
  temptree = prune(big.tree,cp=cpvec[i]) #Pruned tree by cp
  sztree[i] = length(unique(temptree$where)) #Number of leaves
  predicted_value_is = c()
  for(k in nrow(predict(temptree))){
    predicted_value_is = c(predicted_value_is, which.max(predict(temptree)[k,]+2))
  }
  iltree[i] = sum(train$quality!=predicted_value_is) #in-sample loss
  ofit = predict(temptree,val) #Validation prediction
  predicted_value_val = c()
  for(j in nrow(ofit)){
    predicted_value_val = c(predicted_value_val, which.max(ofit[j,]+2))
  }
  oltree[i] = sum(val$quality!=predicted_value_val) #out-of-sample loss
}

### RMSE out-of-sample
oltree=sqrt(oltree/nrow(val))
### RMSE in-sample
iltree = sqrt(iltree/nrow(train)) 


rgl = range(c(iltree,oltree))
plot(range(sztree),rgl,
     type='n', #Type = n removes points from plot
     xlab='Number of Leaves',ylab='Loss')
points(sztree,iltree,
       pch=15, #Type of point
       col='red')
points(sztree,oltree,
       pch=16, #Type of point
       col='blue')
legend("center", #Position of the legend
       legend=c('in-sample','out-of-sample'), #Text in the legend
       pch=c(15,16), #Types of points
       col=c('red','blue')) #Color of pointsenter
```

Here is an example of the data:

```
structure(list(X = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 
64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 
80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 
97, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104), type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("red", "white"), class = "factor"), fixed.acidity = c(7, 
6.3, 8.1, 7.2, 7.2, 8.1, 6.2, 7, 6.3, 8.1, 8.1, 8.6, 7.9, 6.6, 
8.3, 6.6, 6.3, 7.4, 6.5, 6.2, 6.4, 6.8, 7.6, 6.6, 7, 6.9, 7, 
7.4, 7.2, 8.5, 8.3, 7.4, 5.8, 7.3, 6.5, 7, 7.3, 7.3, 6.7, 6.7, 
7, 6.6, 6.7, 7.4, 6.2, 6.2, 7, 6.9, 7.2, 6.6, 6.2, 6.4, 6.9, 
7.2, 6, 6.6, 7.4, 6.8, 6, 7, 6.6, 7.2, 6.2, 6.4, 6.7, 6.7, 7.4, 
6.2, 6.8, 6, 8.6, 6.7, 7.4, 7.1, 7, 7.4, 6.7, 6.8, 7.1, 7.1, 
7.3, 7.1, 7.1, 6.8, 7.1, 7.1, 7.2, 6.1, 6.9, 6.9, 7.5, 7.1, 6, 
8.6, 6, 7.4, 7.1, 6, 7.5, 7.4), volatile.acidity = c(0.27, 0.3, 
0.28, 0.23, 0.23, 0.28, 0.32, 0.27, 0.3, 0.22, 0.27, 0.23, 0.18, 
0.16, 0.42, 0.17, 0.48, 0.34, 0.31, 0.66, 0.31, 0.26, 0.67, 0.27, 
0.25, 0.24, 0.28, 0.27, 0.32, 0.24, 0.14, 0.25, 0.27, 0.28, 0.39, 
0.33, 0.24, 0.24, 0.23, 0.24, 0.31, 0.24, 0.23, 0.18, 0.45, 0.46, 
0.31, 0.19, 0.19, 0.25, 0.16, 0.18, 0.25, 0.21, 0.19, 0.38, 0.2, 
0.22, 0.19, 0.47, 0.38, 0.24, 0.35, 0.26, 0.25, 0.23, 0.24, 0.27, 
0.3, 0.27, 0.23, 0.23, 0.24, 0.18, 0.32, 0.18, 0.54, 0.22, 0.2, 
0.34, 0.22, 0.43, 0.44, 0.25, 0.43, 0.44, 0.39, 0.27, 0.24, 0.21, 
0.17, 0.26, 0.34, 0.265, 0.34, 0.25, 0.12, 0.21, 0.305, 0.25), 
    citric.acid = c(0.36, 0.34, 0.4, 0.32, 0.32, 0.4, 0.16, 0.36, 
    0.34, 0.43, 0.41, 0.4, 0.37, 0.4, 0.62, 0.38, 0.04, 0.42, 
    0.14, 0.48, 0.38, 0.42, 0.14, 0.41, 0.32, 0.35, 0.39, 0.48, 
    0.36, 0.39, 0.34, 0.36, 0.2, 0.43, 0.23, 0.32, 0.39, 0.39, 
    0.39, 0.39, 0.26, 0.27, 0.26, 0.31, 0.26, 0.25, 0.26, 0.35, 
    0.31, 0.29, 0.33, 0.35, 0.35, 0.34, 0.26, 0.15, 0.36, 0.24, 
    0.26, 0.07, 0.15, 0.27, 0.03, 0.24, 0.13, 0.31, 0.29, 0.43, 
    0.23, 0.28, 0.46, 0.31, 0.29, 0.36, 0.34, 0.3, 0.28, 0.31, 
    0.34, 0.2, 0.3, 0.61, 0.62, 0.31, 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.43, 
    0.33, 0.33, 0.32, 0.29, 0.66, 0.36, 0.66, 0.37, 0.32, 0.24, 
    0.4, 0.37), residual.sugar = c(20.7, 1.6, 6.9, 8.5, 8.5, 
    6.9, 7, 20.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1.45, 4.2, 1.2, 1.5, 19.25, 1.5, 
    1.1, 1.1, 7.5, 1.2, 2.9, 1.7, 1.5, 1.3, 9, 1, 8.7, 1.1, 2, 
    10.4, 1.1, 2.05, 14.95, 1.7, 5.4, 1.2, 17.95, 17.95, 2.5, 
    2.9, 7.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 4.4, 4.4, 7.4, 5, 1.6, 1.1, 1.1, 
    1, 1.3, 11.9, 12.4, 4.6, 1.2, 4.9, 12.4, 1.1, 4.6, 1.4, 1.2, 
    6.4, 1.2, 2.1, 10.1, 7.8, 4.6, 4.8, 1, 2.1, 10.1, 1.4, 1.3, 
    8.8, 5.4, 1.4, 16, 6.1, 8.2, 11.8, 11.8, 13.3, 11.8, 11.8, 
    11, 7.5, 1.7, 1.8, 1.7, 12.4, 15.9, 1.2, 15.9, 13.5, 9.6, 
    12.1, 18.9, 13.5), chlorides = c(0.045, 0.049, 0.05, 0.058, 
    0.058, 0.05, 0.045, 0.045, 0.049, 0.044, 0.033, 0.035, 0.04, 
    0.044, 0.04, 0.032, 0.046, 0.033, 0.044, 0.029, 0.038, 0.049, 
    0.074, 0.052, 0.046, 0.052, 0.051, 0.047, 0.033, 0.044, 0.042, 
    0.05, 0.044, 0.08, 0.051, 0.053, 0.057, 0.057, 0.172, 0.173, 
    0.069, 0.057, 0.06, 0.058, 0.063, 0.066, 0.069, 0.067, 0.062, 
    0.068, 0.057, 0.045, 0.039, 0.043, 0.048, 0.044, 0.038, 0.092, 
    0.048, 0.035, 0.044, 0.038, 0.064, 0.04, 0.041, 0.046, 0.05, 
    0.056, 0.061, 0.063, 0.054, 0.046, 0.05, 0.043, 0.042, 0.064, 
    0.06, 0.053, 0.05, 0.063, 0.047, 0.045, 0.044, 0.05, 0.045, 
    0.044, 0.044, 0.049, 0.035, 0.034, 0.04, 0.044, 0.046, 0.034, 
    0.046, 0.06, 0.054, 0.05, 0.059, 0.06), free.sulfur.dioxide = c(45, 
    14, 30, 47, 47, 30, 30, 45, 14, 28, 11, 17, 16, 48, 41, 28, 
    30, 17, 34, 29, 19, 41, 25, 16, 56, 35, 32, 17, 37, 20, 7, 
    31, 22, 21, 25, 38, 45, 45, 63, 63, 28, 33, 33, 38, 63, 62, 
    28, 32, 31, 39, 21, 39, 29, 37, 50, 25, 44, 30, 50, 17, 25, 
    31, 29, 27, 81, 30, 21, 48, 50.5, 31, 9, 30, 21, 31, 20, 
    26, 21, 34, 51, 47, 42, 54, 52, 69, 54, 52, 55, 65, 47, 48, 
    51, 62, 26, 15, 26, 52, 64, 55, 44, 52), total.sulfur.dioxide = c(170, 
    132, 97, 186, 186, 97, 136, 170, 132, 129, 63, 109, 75, 143, 
    172, 112, 99, 171, 133, 75, 102, 122, 168, 142, 245, 146, 
    141, 132, 114, 142, 47, 100, 179, 123, 149, 138, 149, 149, 
    158, 157, 160, 152, 154, 167, 206, 207, 160, 150, 173, 124, 
    82, 108, 191, 213, 147, 78, 111, 123, 147, 151, 78, 122, 
    120, 124, 174, 96, 105, 244, 238.5, 201, 72, 96, 105, 87, 
    69, 103, 105, 114, 166, 164, 207, 155, 152, 202, 155, 152, 
    156, 243, 136, 136, 148, 240, 164, 80, 164, 192, 162, 164, 
    170, 192), density = c(1.001, 0.994, 0.9951, 0.9956, 0.9956, 
    0.9951, 0.9949, 1.001, 0.994, 0.9938, 0.9908, 0.9947, 0.992, 
    0.9912, 1.0002, 0.9914, 0.9928, 0.9917, 0.9955, 0.9892, 0.9912, 
    0.993, 0.9937, 0.9951, 0.9955, 0.993, 0.9961, 0.9914, 0.9906, 
    0.9974, 0.9934, 0.992, 0.9962, 0.9905, 0.9934, 0.9906, 0.9999, 
    0.9999, 0.9937, 0.9937, 0.9954, 0.9934, 0.9934, 0.9931, 0.994, 
    0.9939, 0.9954, 0.995, 0.9917, 0.9914, 0.991, 0.9911, 0.9908, 
    0.9962, 0.9972, 0.9931, 0.9926, 0.9951, 0.9972, 0.991, 0.9931, 
    0.9927, 0.9934, 0.9903, 0.992, 0.9926, 0.9962, 0.9956, 0.9958, 
    0.9964, 0.9941, 0.9926, 0.9962, 0.9898, 0.9912, 0.9961, 0.9949, 
    0.9929, 0.9985, 0.9946, 0.9966, 0.9974, 0.9975, 0.9972, 0.9974, 
    0.9975, 0.9974, 0.9957, 0.99, 0.9899, 0.9916, 0.9969, 0.9979, 
    0.9913, 0.9979, 0.9975, 0.9962, 0.997, 1, 0.9975), pH = c(3, 
    3.3, 3.26, 3.19, 3.19, 3.26, 3.18, 3, 3.3, 3.22, 2.99, 3.14, 
    3.18, 3.54, 2.98, 3.25, 3.24, 3.12, 3.22, 3.33, 3.17, 3.47, 
    3.05, 3.42, 3.25, 3.45, 3.38, 3.19, 3.1, 3.2, 3.47, 3.19, 
    3.37, 3.19, 3.24, 3.13, 3.21, 3.21, 3.11, 3.1, 3.13, 3.22, 
    3.24, 3.16, 3.27, 3.25, 3.13, 3.36, 3.35, 3.34, 3.32, 3.31, 
    3.13, 3.09, 3.3, 3.11, 3.36, 3.03, 3.3, 3.02, 3.11, 3.15, 
    3.22, 3.22, 3.14, 3.33, 3.13, 3.1, 3.32, 3.69, 2.95, 3.33, 
    3.13, 3.26, 3.31, 2.94, 3.27, 3.39, 3.21, 3.17, 3.33, 3.11, 
    3.12, 3.22, 3.11, 3.12, 3.09, 3.12, 3.26, 3.25, 3.21, 3.04, 
    3.14, 2.95, 3.14, 3, 3.4, 3.34, 2.99, 3), sulphates = c(0.45, 
    0.49, 0.44, 0.4, 0.4, 0.44, 0.47, 0.45, 0.49, 0.45, 0.56, 
    0.53, 0.63, 0.52, 0.67, 0.55, 0.36, 0.53, 0.5, 0.39, 0.35, 
    0.48, 0.51, 0.47, 0.5, 0.44, 0.53, 0.49, 0.71, 0.53, 0.4, 
    0.44, 0.37, 0.42, 0.35, 0.28, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.34, 0.46, 
    0.56, 0.56, 0.53, 0.52, 0.52, 0.46, 0.48, 0.44, 0.58, 0.46, 
    0.35, 0.52, 0.5, 0.36, 0.38, 0.34, 0.46, 0.36, 0.34, 0.38, 
    0.46, 0.54, 0.49, 0.42, 0.64, 0.35, 0.51, 0.6, 0.71, 0.49, 
    0.64, 0.35, 0.37, 0.65, 0.56, 0.37, 0.77, 0.6, 0.42, 0.46, 
    0.45, 0.46, 0.48, 0.45, 0.46, 0.44, 0.47, 0.4, 0.41, 0.44, 
    0.42, 0.5, 0.36, 0.5, 0.44, 0.41, 0.39, 0.46, 0.44), alcohol = c(8.8, 
    9.5, 10.1, 9.9, 9.9, 10.1, 9.6, 8.8, 9.5, 11, 12, 9.7, 10.8, 
    12.4, 9.7, 11.4, 9.6, 11.3, 9.5, 12.8, 11, 10.5, 9.3, 10, 
    10.4, 10, 10.5, 11.6, 12.3, 10, 10.2, 10.8, 10.2, 12.8, 10, 
    11.2, 8.6, 8.6, 9.4, 9.4, 9.8, 9.5, 9.5, 10, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 
    9.8, 11.7, 11, 10.9, 10.9, 11, 9.6, 8.9, 10.2, 9.9, 8.6, 
    8.9, 10.5, 10.2, 10.3, 9.1, 12.6, 9.8, 10.7, 9.5, 9, 9.5, 
    10, 9.1, 10.7, 9.5, 12.7, 12, 9.3, 9, 10.6, 9.2, 10, 9.5, 
    8.7, 8.7, 9.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 9, 12.6, 12.6, 11.5, 9.2, 8.8, 
    11.4, 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, 9.4, 9, 9.1), quality = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("3", "4", 
    "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", 
"61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", 
"72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", 
"83", "84", "85", "86", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", 
"95", "96", "97", "98", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105"
), class = "data.frame")
```

The result I'm getting on the chart doesn't seem right based on what I'm used to. I think it should be more rounded in terms of the points on the graph. At the moment, it just doesn't look right to me. Does anyone have any ideas what might going on? Any feedback provided is very appreciated.

[image: Results]